# Sharing via intent linkedin crashing with permission denial

Tags: java, android, android-intent, linkedin-api

I am trying to share stuff via linkedin app

Here is the code

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBarAppTheme">

            <intent
                android:action="android.intent.action.SEND"
                android:targetPackage="com.linkedin.android"
                android:targetClass="com.linkedin.android.home.v2.UpdateStatusActivity"
                />

            </activity>
```

My intent code is

```
 if(Utilities.doesPackageExist(getActivity(), "com.linkedin.android"))
                {
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setClassName("com.linkedin.android",
                            "com.linkedin.android.home.v2.UpdateStatusActivity");
                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);
                    startActivity(shareIntent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please install the LinkedIn app to share your result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain flg=0x1 cmp=com.linkedin.android/.home.v2.UpdateStatusActivity (has clip) (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{538be710 4331:com.devicebee.workedin/u0a98} (pid=4331, uid=10098) not exported from uid 10131
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the code

There is no `<intent>` element in the Android manifest, at least according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

> I get this error

As the error message tells you, the activity that you are trying to use is not exported. "Not exported" means that third party apps cannot start that activity. It is a private activity for the LinkedIn app; only the LinkedIn app can start that activity.

Comment: the activity that you are trying to use is not exported. Can u explain this a bit more? Can i share to linkedIn via share intent?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar: "Can u explain this a bit more?" -- I added some more to the answer. "Can i share to linkedIn via share intent?" -- I have no idea, but `ACTION_SEND` would certainly be a better course of action. Please share where the user wants to share; use `ACTION_SEND` to support sharing content by MIME type, and allow whatever apps honor that (LinkedIn and others) to share.

Answer (score 0):

set this code at android manifest file in the Application tag.

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to perform LinkedIn sharing on Android via the official Linked Android SDK as the officially supported method.  You can download the SDK here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads#androidsdk

Details about how to share content using it are available here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin